# How can I print text based on the value in a dropdown menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I tried making a tkinter script which would print a set of jobs according to the day selected in the dropdown menu, but it isn't working and I can't find any solution. Appreciate your help!
My code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
Label(root, text="Day").pack()
OPTIONS = [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
    "Sunday"

]
variable = StringVar()
variable.set("Day")
w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *OPTIONS).pack()


def day():
    if variable == "Monday":
        print("Hello")



Button(root, text="Enter", command=day).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `variable.get()`.`variable` is a `StringVar` instance.

Comment: Read up on [The Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Thre problems on your code.

```
variable = StringVar()
w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *OPTIONS).pack()
# Try to set the value here will make more sence if you reed it back
# after some weeks. Plus try to use week days. "Day" is not a week day
# and in the future will prevent an error... I know better
variable.set(OPTIONS[0])
```

```
def day():
    # You forget .get() and alos I suggest to use .lower()
    if variable.get().lower() == "monday":
        print("Hello")
```

````
# Lambda will prevet that code to bexecuted before button is pressed
Button(root, text="Enter", command=lambda:day()).pack()
```
````